# Equivalent of Java triple shift operator (>>>) in C#?

Tags: c#, java, bitwise-operators

What is the equivalent (in C#) of Java's `>>>` operator?

(Just to clarify, I'm not referring to the `>>` and `<<` operators.)

Comment: There is no <<< operator in Java, only a >>> operator.

Comment: C# 11 supports >>> operator. check [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880172/equivalent-of-java-triple-shift-operator-in-c/73533057#73533057) and here is [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#unsigned-right-shift-operator-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Edit: The [Unsigned right-shift operator >>>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#unsigned-right-shift-operator-) is now also available in C# 11 and later.

For earlier C# versions, you can use unsigned integer types, and then the `<<` and `>>` do what you expect. The [MSDN documentation on shift operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377(VS.71).aspx) gives you the details.

Since Java doesn't support unsigned integers (apart from `char`), this additional operator became necessary.

Comment: C# 11 supports >>> operator. check [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880172/equivalent-of-java-triple-shift-operator-in-c/73533057#73533057) and here is [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#unsigned-right-shift-operator-)

Answer (score 17):

Java doesn't have an unsigned left shift (`<<<`), but either way, you can just cast to `uint` and shfit from there.

E.g.

```
(int)((uint)foo >> 2); // temporarily cast to uint, shift, then cast back to int
```

Comment: Java doesn't?  or C# doesn't?

Comment: C# doesn't have any 'unsigned shift' operators. Java has an unsigned RIGHT shift, but not an unsigned LEFT shift.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your input on this. Will keep it in mind for when I am forced to use signed types.

Comment: There's no need for <<< because sign-extension isn't relevant for left shifts.

Comment: Just to get this straight - the Java equivalent of the C# operation 1 << 4 would be (int)((uint)1 >> 4); ??

Answer (score 2):

Upon reading this, I hope my conclusion of use as follows is correct.
If not, insights appreciated.

Java

```
i >>>= 1;
```

C#:

```
i = (int)((uint)i >> 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

n >>> s in Java is equivalent to TripleShift(n,s) where:

```
    private static long TripleShift(long n, int s)
    {
        if (n >= 0)
            return n >> s;
        return (n >> s) + (2 << ~s);
    }
```

Comment: Head to head testing reveals this approach doesn't match Java for long, but does for smaller integral types.

Answer (score 1):

There is no >>> operator in C#. But you can convert your value like int,long,Int16,Int32,Int64 to unsigned uint, ulong, UInt16,UInt32,UInt64 etc.

Here is the example.

```
    private long getUnsignedRightShift(long value,int s)
    {
        return (long)((ulong)value >> s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 11 and later supports `>>>` Unsigned right shift operator

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#unsigned-right-shift-operator-

Answer (score 0):

For my **VB.Net** folks

The suggested answers above will give you overflow exceptions with `Option Strict ON`

Try this for example `-100 >>> 2` with above solutions:

The following code works always for `>>>`

```
Function RShift3(ByVal a As Long, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
        If a >= 0 Then
            Return a >> n
        Else
            Return (a >> n) + (2 << (Not n))
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Sebastien Lebreton i had not seen your solution before posting this