# Java has operator >>> and <<< which are a bit different - please help

Tags: c#, java, bit-manipulation, operations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of Java triple shift operators (>>> and <<<) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880172/equivalent-of-java-triple-shift-operators-and-in-c)

Java has operator >>> and <<< which are a bit different then >> and << - can anyone give me its equivalent in C# ?

Comment: There is no `<<<` operator. There is no need for it as left shift semantics are the same for signed and unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest (or at least most logical) equivalent is effectively an unchecked cast to the equivalent unsigned type, followed by a normal shift and then potentially a cast back again:

```
// To perform int result = x >>> 5;
int x = -10;

uint u = unchecked ((uint) x);
u = u >> 5;

int result = unchecked ((int) u);
```

(The unchecked part is only relevant if you're otherwise in a checked context, of course.)

In my experience, times where you *normally* want to use `>>>` in Java, you'd just use unsigned types to start with in C#.

Answer (score 2):

There is no c# equivalent, if you use an unsigned value on the left, `>>` in c# will perform the same function as `>>>` in java.

You therefore need to cast to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Java has `>>>` (I don' think there is a `<<<` operator) which is the unsigned right shift operator that is not present in c#. It is there in java as java has not unsigned data types. In c# just use an unsigned type with `>>` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`>>>` is an  unsigned shift operations in Java.

They don't have an equivalent in C# because C# supports unsigned integers and hence you can just shift on those.