# What is code for logical right shift in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I am trying to translate Java code with logical right shift (`>>>`) ([Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)) to C#

Java code is

```
 return hash >>> 24 ^ hash & 0xFFFFFF;
```

C# is marked `>>>` as syntax error.

How to fix that?

**Update 1**
People recommend to use `>>` in C#, but it didn't solve problem.

```
System.out.println("hash 1 !!! = " + (-986417464>>>24));
```

is 197

but

```
Console.WriteLine("hash 1 !!! = " + (-986417464 >> 24));
```

is -59

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Java triple shift operator (>>>) in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880172/equivalent-of-java-triple-shift-operator-in-c)

Comment: Also [What is the C# equivalent of Java unsigned right shift operator >>>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8125127/18192)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java needed to introduce `>>>` because its only unsigned type is `char`, whose operations are done in integers.

C#, on the other hand, has unsigned types, which perform right shift without sign extension:

```
uint h = (uint)hash;
return h >> 24 ^ h & 0xFFFFFF;
```

Comment: No, it is not. For example 
System.out.println("hash 2 !!! = " + (-986417464>>>24));
is 197

but 
Console.WriteLine("hash 1 !!! = " + (-986417464 >> 24));
is -59

Comment: But why it is not equal in my example Console.WriteLine("hash 1 !!! = " + (-986417464 >> 24)); ?

Comment: @ArthurKhusnutdinov Because you are shifting an `int`, not a `uint`. `-986417464` is `int` by default. You need to add a cast ([link](http://ideone.com/N7ze1W)).

Answer (score 0):

For C# you can just use `>>`

> If the left-hand operand is of type `uint` or `ulong`, the right-shift operator performs a *logical shift*: the high-order empty bit positions are always set to zero.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#right-shift-operator-).

Comment: No, it is not. For example 
System.out.println("hash 2 !!! = " + (-986417464>>>24));
is 197

but 
Console.WriteLine("hash 1 !!! = " + (-986417464 >> 24));
is -59

Comment: The answer of dasblinkenlight shows how to solve exactly that issue.

Comment: This answer was correct; just wasn't explained too great. A quote goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Logical ("unsigned") Right Shift operator >>> is supported from C# 11.